# What does apache return when a GET comes in for a file that's in the process of being replaced?

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I can't find the answer on google and this seems pretty difficult to test with certainty.  So, I am really hoping that someone out there just knows what actually happens.

What happens if a GET comes in for a file at the exact moment the file is being replaced?  (**EDIT:** The file is being replaced by ant's `<copy>` task.)

Is this transparently handled by some filesystem locking, and apache simply waits for replacement to complete before returning the replacement file?  Does it return the pre-replacement file?  Or does it return the file in its intermediary state?

This particular instance is Apache/2.4.7 on Ubuntu-14.04.

Comment: That depends entirely on _how_ the file is being "replaced".

Comment: Ant's `<copy>` task.  Question updated.